# If a div contains a specific string of text, edit the parent's css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'd love some help with a simple jQuery script that searches for a specific string of text. If that text exists, then manipulate the containing div's css. The HTML would look like:

```
<div class="container">
    <div>
        <div class="heading">
            <a href="#">Very important text</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div>
        <div class="heading">
            <a href="#">Not important at all</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div>
        <div class="heading">
            <a href="#">Very important text</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div>
        <div class="heading">
            <a href="#">Not important at all</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

For example: If a container contains the string "Very important text" I would like to give the 'heading' class a height of 200px and its 'container' div a background of green. Please let me know if this is unclear. Thanks in advance!

CHeers.

Comment: Could you as easily apply the same rules to .html instead of .container
So that any string found in any html file that contains that exact string could be manipulated?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use *:contains* selector in Jquery .

```
$(".container .heading a:contains('Very important text')").each(function(i , v){
    $(this).closest(".heading").css("height" , "200px");
    $(this).closest(".container").css("background-color" , "green");
});
```

or simply

```
$(".container .heading a:contains('Very important text')")
        .closest(".heading").css("height" , "200px")
        .closest(".container").css("background-color" , "green");
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uGjA9/1/)

Answer (score 3):

You can do this:

```
$('.container').filter(':contains("Very important text")')
.css('background-color', 'green')
.find('.heading').css('height', '200px');
```

Demo:http://jsfiddle.net/AmitJoki/y82X9/1

As Zword suggested, use filter. This solution is the fastest. [JSPerf](http://jsperf.com/so-22877172)

Comment: suppose if you div container have contains some thing text if your above code will be confused.

Comment: The code is fairly self explanatory. Find the div that contains the text and apply the css to it, and then find the the `.heading` and apply css to it as well. What's confusing in it?

Comment: This solution is surely good but just telling it would be good if you use filter .See test : http://jsperf.com/so-22877172

Answer (score 0):

Using filter is a faster and better option:

```
$(".container .heading a").filter(":contains('Very important text')").closest(".heading").css("height","200px").closest(".container").css("background-color", "green");
```

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tm22X/)

See test : http://jsperf.com/so-22877172

Comment: he said background color for conatiner class not heading class

Answer (score 0):

just use this ..

$(".container  div:contains('Very important text')").parent().css("height","300");

you can play around .